# Отменить запрос гео положения посетителя через js

Tags: javascript, геолокация

Простите пожалуйста за крайне нубский вопрос, но..
Есть страница, которая запрашивает у пользователя определение гео ( navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition), по ссылке [весь скрипт](https://n198225.yclients.com/app.1555078905393.js) 
надо этот запрос убрать и не спрашивать ничего у пользователя, вообще отключить определение гео позиции, но (!) все что у меня есть, это возможность вставить свой произвольный JS код вниз страницы, больше доступа никакого нет, ни к телу страницы, ни тем более к подключенным js файлам =( реализуема ли такая задача вообще? Если да, то пните в нужную сторону. Спасибо.

Comment: Каким образом вы можете *вставить свой произвольный JS код вниз страницы*, если нет возможности модифицировать js? Расскажите поподробнее.

Comment: Сама страница с формой генерируется сторонней CRM системой, все, что они мне предоставляют, как клиенту, это ссылку на страницу с формой, скрипт для установки кнопки с формой на мой сайт и возможность добавить кусочек произвольного js кода (в основном это используется для подключения метрик-аналитик и прочей лабуды, но по сути можно любой js код вставить.). Делаю я это в личном кабинете в специальном окошечке) сразу скажу, саппорт данной crm-системы не знает ответа на этот вопрос)

Comment: Можно попробовать переопределить функцию `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` - на вашу собственну, которая не будет ничего запрашивать у пользователя. Сложно сказать что-то более конкретное без воспроизводимого примера.

Comment: Спасибо Вам просто нереальное, сама не додумалась, действительно переопределение решило вопрос.

Comment: Если вы знаете ответ на ваш вопрос, то можно его опубликовать! Кому-то в будущем это может понадобиться.